# Linq statements need optimizing

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have written the following code:

```
//get the user from the DB
var tmpuser = _db.aspnet_Users.First(q => q.UserName == user.Identity.Name);

//list the direct connections to Verbond
List<Verbond> verb1 = tmpuser.UsersVerbondens
                             .Where(q => q.Schooljaar.Sch_Schooljaar == schooljaarparam)
                             .Select(q => q.Verbond)
                             .ToList();

//list the connected Facturatieverbonden
List<FacturatieVerbonden> verb2 = tmpuser.UsersFacturatieVerbondens
                                         .Where(q => q.Schooljaar.Sch_Schooljaar == schooljaarparam)
                                         .Select(q => q.FacturatieVerbonden)
                                         .ToList();

//loop through the facturatieverbonden and add their verbonds to the first list
foreach (FacturatieVerbonden v in verb2) {
    verb1.AddRange(v.Verbonds);
}

//make a distinct list
List<Verbond> test = verb1.Distinct().ToList();
```

So, Users can be connected to 0 or more `facturatieverbonden` and also can be connected to `verbond`.

A `facturatieverbonden` can have one or more `verbond`'s under itself.

What I need is a list of all the `verbond`'s the user is connected to, directly, or indirectly via the `facturatieverbonden`.

My code works but I don't think it's very efficient. Any hints on making it cleaner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query isn't very LINQy. Here's a potential improvement:

```
           //list the direct connections to Verbond 
var test = (from q in tmpuser.UsersVerbondens
            where q.Schooljaar.Sch_Schooljaar == schooljaarparam
            select q.Verbond)
           //return distinct values
           .Union
           //list the connected Facturatieverbonden 
           (from q in tmpuser.UsersFacturatieVerbondens
            where q.Schooljaar.Sch_Schooljaar == schooljaarparam
            from v in q.FacturatieVerbonden.Verbonds
            select v)
           //return a List
           .ToList();
```

By making `ToList` the very last thing it does, the whole computation can be done in the database, avoiding all the intermediate lists.

Comment: Good idea but small problem: q.Verbond and vf.Verbonds (plural) are different types.

Comment: David B: That's the problem with programming in a foreign language -- it's hard to tell when something doesn't make sense. Do I have it right now?

Answer (score 0):

Your performance problem is here.  Each AddRange call will enumerate v.Verbonds, and each will be a database roundtrip.

```
//loop through the facturatieverbonden and add their verbonds to the first list 
foreach (FacturatieVerbonden v in verb2) { 
    verb1.AddRange(v.Verbonds); 
}
```

To fix it:

```
//query the connected Facturatieverbonden 
IQueryable<FacturatieVerbonden> verbQuery2 = tmpuser.UsersFacturatieVerbondens 
  .Where(q => q.Schooljaar.Sch_Schooljaar == schooljaarparam) 
  .Select(q => q.FacturatieVerbonden);

verb1.AddRange(verbQuery2.SelectMany(fv => fv.Verbonds));
```

There's still plenty of room to tighten the performance, but at least this address the gross problem.  You could easily observe a 10 times speed up.